# CSS get the before pseudo element to appear below the actual element

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS which places the before pseudo element on top of the actual element, but I need it to appear below.

Is this possible. I've seen lots of similar posts and taken all the advice but still can't get it to work. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/6wsyqrwx/

```
div {
      height: 224px;
      width: 294px;
      border:7px solid #FFF;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
      margin:50px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);  /*Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: rotate(-3deg);
      z-index:auto;
      background:red;
      position: relative;
    }

div::before {
      height: 224px;
      width: 294px;
      border:7px solid #FFF;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(6deg); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);  /*Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: rotate(6deg);
      background:blue;
      display:block;
      content:'';
      z-index:-1;
      position:absolute;
    }
```

Comment: change `z-index` like `div::before {z-index:0;}`

Comment: I don't think you can move child element below parent.

Comment: or try something like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wsyqrwx/9/) without rotating the top div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `transform` properties. It will not go well with position items. Have a look at below fiddle without `transform`.

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/6wsyqrwx/7/

```
div {
      height: 224px;
      width: 294px;
      border:7px solid #FFF;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
      margin:50px;
      z-index:auto;
      background:red;
      position: relative;
    }

div::before {
      height: 224px;
      width: 294px;
      border:7px solid #FFF;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
      background:blue;
      display:block;
      content:'bottom';
      z-index:-1;
      position:absolute;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmmm, I see your point... So it looks like there's no way to get around this and have the elements rotated. Am I right???

Comment: as per knowledge.. almost no way :)

Answer (score 1):

As Kiran Varthi mentions in his answer, this seems to be a problem due to the `transform` properties. You could achieve the desired effect by using the `::after` pseudo element instead of styling the `div`.

```css
div {
      height: 238px;
      width: 308px;
      margin:50px;
      position: relative;
    }
div::after {
      height: 224px;
      width: 294px;
      border:7px solid #FFF;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);  /*Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: rotate(-3deg);
      display:block;
      content:'top';
      background:red;
      position: absolute;
    }
div::before {
      height: 224px;
      width: 294px;
      border:7px solid #FFF;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(6deg); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);  /*Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: rotate(6deg);
      background:blue;
      display:block;
      content:'bottom';
      position:absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tkd3L6ns/

Comment: A good idea, but in the long term, the div is going to contain dynamic (HTML based) content. So that might not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch `divs` places - put `:after` on the *top* element:

```css
div {
    height: 224px;
    width: 294px;
    border:7px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
    /*Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(6deg);
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
}
div:after {
    content:'top';
    position:absolute;
    height: 224px;
    width: 294px;
    border:7px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
    margin:50px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    /*Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>bottom</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/6wsyqrwx/8/)

Note: I didn't position them like you did, this just shows that it can be done with one pseudo element (`:after`) and using `transform`.

Comment: +1 While the principle is the same, this is a bit tidier than my solution.